# How do I find starting values to fit nonlinear data?

Tags: r, parameters, estimation, nonlinear-optimization

I am attempting to calculate the two parameters that best minimize the least squares of a nonlinear model (below). I have searched for a good method for this on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but to no avail.

#### The data

```
x<-c(0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0);
y<-c(0,0.501766379,0.508975489, 0.531691175, 0.503410116, 0.539983481, 0.551075694, 0.695050048, 1);
data1 <- data.frame(x,y)
```

#### The Model

```
y~(a*x^2+x*(1-x))/(a*x^2+2*x*(1-x)+b*(1-x)^2)
```

#### My meager efforts

```
min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
with(data, sum((par[1]*x^2+x*(1-x))/(par[1]*x^2+2*x*(1-x)+par[2]*(1-x)^2)))
           }
result <- optim(par = c(0, 1), min.RSS, data = data1$y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using the nls function. I was concerned about attaining suitable starting values, but nls my concerns appeared to be unfounded, as any reasonable starting values work.

The solution:

```
m<-nls(y ~ (a*x^2+x*(1-x))/(a*x^2+2*x*(1-x)+b*(1-x)^2), start=list(a=1,b=.5))
beta <- coefficients(m)
```

This yields the desired parameters (in object "beta").